# Getting referrer in asp net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http

I need to get referrer , when user is redirected from other site to my own , i trying get referrer from headers but its empty. All attempts returns null or empty :

`Request.UrlReferrer`
`HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["Referer"].ToString()`
`ServerVariables["http_referer"]`

and if you look to request headers in browser , i will not find referrer header.

tried get referrer from javascript `document.referrer` but its returns empty string

can somebody please explain why there is no referrer header and how i can get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `Referrer URLs` are passed between two unrelated sites (from one site to another) when navigation occurs by clicking a link or JavaScript-based navigation. `Referrer URLs` are not sent if the user uses the browsers address bar, back/forward buttons/ etc.. to navigate.

There are several reasons why the `Referrer URL` is empty in a request.

- For some (security/privacy) reasons, the `Referrer URL` is stripped out
  when navigating from a **HTTPS** site to a **HTTP** site (e.g. from
  https://google.com to http://example.com).
- It can also be stripped out using some other JavaScript
  and HTML tricks.

once `Referrer URL` has been stripped out, There is no way to disable this behavior to get it back.